# Access JSON object based on the value of another JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Kindly forgive me for my subject line. Couldn't understand what to put.

I have some dynamically generated data. The data is similar this.

```
var TypeA ={ "length" : "100" , "width" :"80" , "color" : "#ffffff" }    
var TypeB ={ "length" : "150" , "width" :"120" , "color" : "#4286f4" }
var TypeC ={ "length" : "150" , "width" :"120" , "color" : "#4202f4" }
```

The above few JSONs define the properties for type A , B, C respectively. (In actual ,there are many types.)

Now I have the actual data as below :

```
 var data =[{id : "1" , label : "A1" , type : "TypeA" },
            {id : "2" , label : "A2" , type : "TypeA" },
            {id : "3" , label : "B1" , type : "TypeB" },
            {id : "4" , label : "A3" , type : "TypeA" },
            {id : "5" , label : "C1" , type : "TypeC" },
            {id : "6" , label : "B2" , type : "TypeB" }
            ]
```

Now I'm running loop through the `data` .In this loop I need to access the Type properties based on the `type` defined in data JSON.

I'm doing something like this, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$.each(JSON.parse(data), function(index,jsonObject){
      console.log("ColorCode : "+ jsonObject.type.color);
 });
```

Can anyone help me how can I access the type properties here. Thanks.

Comment: You actually don't have any JSON here..

Comment: `jsonObject.type` is a string! How do you expect to access its `color` property? It doesn't have any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example you gave, you have defined one variable per type definition. It's making them harder to access. Instead, you should have either this:

```
var types = {
  "TypeA": { "length" : "100" , "width" :"80" , "color" : "#ffffff" },
  "TypeB": { "length" : "150" , "width" :"120" , "color" : "#4286f4" },
  "TypeC": { "length" : "150" , "width" :"120" , "color" : "#4202f4" }
};
```

or this:

```
var TypeA ={ "length" : "100" , "width" :"80" , "color" : "#ffffff" };  
var TypeB ={ "length" : "150" , "width" :"120" , "color" : "#4286f4" };
var TypeC ={ "length" : "150" , "width" :"120" , "color" : "#4202f4" };
var types = {
  "TypeA": TypeA,
  "TypeB": TypeB,
  "TypeC": TypeC
};
```

Then, it's easy to do this:

```
JSON.parse(data).forEach(function(el) {
  console.log("ColorCode : " + types[el.type].color);
});
```

### Demo

```js
var types = {
  "TypeA": { "length": "100", "width": "80", "color": "#ffffff" },
  "TypeB": { "length": "150", "width": "120", "color": "#4286f4" },
  "TypeC": { "length": "150", "width": "120", "color": "#4202f4" }
};

var data =[
  {id : "1" , label : "A1" , type : "TypeA" },
  {id : "2" , label : "A2" , type : "TypeA" },
  {id : "3" , label : "B1" , type : "TypeB" },
  {id : "4" , label : "A3" , type : "TypeA" },
  {id : "5" , label : "C1" , type : "TypeC" },
  {id : "6" , label : "B2" , type : "TypeB" }
];

data.forEach(function (el) {
  console.log("ColorCode : " + types[el.type].color);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend, You to define the `Type` in a object

```
var obj = {
  "TypeA": {.... },
  "TypeB": {.... },,
  "TypeC": {.... },
};
```

then you can easily use [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to access the property based string key.

```
 $.each(data, function(index,jsonObject){
      console.log("ColorCode : ", obj[jsonObject.type].color);
 });
```

```js
var obj = {
  "TypeA": {
    "length": "100",
    "width": "80",
    "color": "#ffffff"
  },
  "TypeB": {
    "length": "150",
    "width": "120",
    "color": "#4286f4"
  },
  "TypeC": {
    "length": "150",
    "width": "120",
    "color": "#4202f4"
  }
};

var data = [{
    id: "1",
    label: "A1",
    type: "TypeA"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    label: "A2",
    type: "TypeA"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    label: "B1",
    type: "TypeB"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    label: "A3",
    type: "TypeA"
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    label: "C1",
    type: "TypeC"
  },
  {
    id: "6",
    label: "B2",
    type: "TypeB"
  }
]

 $.each(data, function(index,jsonObject){
      console.log("ColorCode : ", obj[jsonObject.type].color);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

call the variables with `window`.

```js
var TypeA ={ "length" : "100" , "width" :"80" , "color" : "#ffffff" }    
var TypeB ={ "length" : "150" , "width" :"120" , "color" : "#4286f4" }
var TypeC ={ "length" : "150" , "width" :"120" , "color" : "#4202f4" }

var dataO = [{id : "1" , label : "A1" , type : "TypeA" },
            {id : "2" , label : "A2" , type : "TypeA" },
            {id : "3" , label : "B1" , type : "TypeB" },
            {id : "4" , label : "A3" , type : "TypeA" },
            {id : "5" , label : "C1" , type : "TypeC" },
            {id : "6" , label : "B2" , type : "TypeB" }];

/*The data is already parsed.*/

dataO.forEach(function(key, index){
  console.log(window[key.type].color);
});

/*dataO.forEach(key => console.log(window[key.type].color));*/
```

Comment: What if the variables are not defined in the global scope?